# how to update value inside the while loop in php

Tags: php

hi everyone im creating simple posting grade online.
the problem is how i can save all value inside the while loop

here is the code

```
 $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsubjecschedule  where  sched_id='".$col."'  ")or die(mysql_error());
 while($val=mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){

    $Subject=$val['Subject'];
 }

 echo "<tr><td width=''><font face='Arial' size='3pt'>Subjec Code</td><td width=''><font face='Arial' size='3pt'>".$Subject."</td></tr><tr>
 <td width=''><font face='Arial' size=''>Student Name</td>
 <td width=''><font face='Arial' size=''>Course</td>

 <td width=''><font face='Arial' size=''>Prelim</td>
 <td width=''><font face='Arial' size=''>Midterm</td>
 <td width=''><font face='Arial' size=''>Semi</td>
 <td width=''><font face='Arial' size=''>Final</td>
 </tr>";
      echo "</thead>
<tfoot></tfoot>
<tbody>";


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblstudntsub  where Sublink='".$control."' order by studname ASC")or die(mysql_error());


 $a=0;
 $b=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
$id=$row['id'];
$name=$row['studname'];
$cor=$row['course'];
$yl=$row['YearLevel'];





    echo"<tr bgcolor='#E6E6E6'>
    <td align='left'><p align='left'>".$b.".".$name."</p><input type='hidden' name='cont[$a]' value=".$id."></td>
    <td><p align='left'>".$cor."</p></td>

    <td> <input type='text' name='pre[$a]' value=''style='width:40px;'></td>
    <td> <input type='text' name='mid[$a]' value=''style='width:40px;' ></td>
    <td> <input type='text' name='semi[$a]' value=''style='width:40px;' ></td>
    <td> <input type='text' name='fin[$a]' value=''style='width:40px;' ></td>



    </tr>"; 
    $a++;
    $b++;
        }

      echo  "   <tr><td>
    <input type='submit' name='save[$a]' value='Save'/>
 </td></tr>";

echo "</tbody><table>";
```

sorry for my bad grammar hope you understand what i mean.

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: Saving which value to what? And what is `$a` supposed to do?

Comment: i mean update to tblstudntsub, $a is a counter to the value. sir

Comment: use arrays to store mysql values

Comment: can u give me some example sir? cuz i realy dont get it. 

hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Construct an array for each value and store data to it.

Comment: but i dont know how to do it sir. can you give me some example ?

sorry im just a beginner hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

better to write code inside the loop like this

```
while(.......)
{
    ...
?>

<tr>
<td>fdsf</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what you mean sir is another loop inside loop?
can you give some example?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array to save all the subject,
Like

```
$subject= array();
$i=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($records))
{
$subject[$i]=$row['subject'];
$i++;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: what i mean sir is how to update the tblstudntsub pre,mid,semi,final
from input type='text' value inside the while loop hope you understand